# Inner flexbox grow to fit (limited) space available

Tags: css, flexbox

am trying to achieve nested flexbox layout where there are two text divs that comprise an inner flexbox, both of which should be the same size and truncate (with ellipsis) if the text won't fit.

I can get this working fine if I flatten into a single flexbox as show in the pen below ("flattened version"). But am having trouble preventing the inner flexbox version from growing too big for the space available. Am not sure what is determining the size of the inner flexbox!

I am trying to get to...

```
+------- outer flexbox -----+
|   +---inner flexbox---+   |
|A|A|text1 ...|text2 ...|A|A|
|   +-------------------+   |
+---------------------------+
```

where:

- outer flexbox has a fixed width and cannot grow
- there is no text wrapping anywhere (`white-space: nowrap`)
- all 'A' divs will be sized according to content
- both 'text' divs are the same width and will overflow with ellipsis

Codepen: https://codepen.io/jugglingcats/pen/jOMErpB

Answer (score 0):

Used suggestion in this post: [Equal but dynamically-sized columns with overflow ellipsis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62919214/equal-but-dynamically-sized-columns-with-overflow-ellipsis) using grid.

```
.inner {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 2px;
}
```

Working pen: https://codepen.io/jugglingcats/pen/jOMEMNG

Still not sure why flexbox isn't working well in this case though!